# Magento send email in custom module

Tags: magento, email-templates

I Need to create an email template. Also I need to load that customer template into another `.phtml` file and edit before send the email. After editing only I need to send the email. Can anyone please help me how to do this?

I searched and tried for this, but I only found articles related to send email without editing the existing email template.

example: http://www.caritorsolutions.com/blog/158-send-email-from-custom-module-in-magento

Comment: You can create a new transactional email in the backend, and assign variable to accomodate your custom fields/values/html. Then this email template can be called anywhere in your code, and sent with your dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an email template when going to System > Transactional Emails. The name you put in is the unique identifier for that template.

```
<?php

$templateName = 'template_name_you_put_in_in_the_backend';

$to = 'johndoe@example.com';
$customerName   = 'John Doe';

// Load our template by template_id
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($templateId);

$vars = array(
    'customer_name' => $customerName
    // Other vars that can be used in the mplate
);

// Store sends it
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
$emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName);
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail); 

//Send the email!
$emailTemplate->send($to, $customerName, $emailTemplateVariables);
```

You can of course edit this file through System > Transactional Emails. If this isn't what you mean, can you clarify what you mean by 'editing the existing email template' ?